# Why does my object disappear?

Tags: python, class

I have an issue with an object I created and then use in a function.

```
class environnement:
    def __init__(self, n, dic={}, listr=[], listf=[]):
        self.taille=n
        self.reg=dict(dic)
        self.raccess=listr
        self.faccess=listf
```

First I create an environment in my function `compilProgram` and then I use  `compilInstruction` with this environnement:

```
def compilProgram(fichierSortie, nbrRegDispo, AST):
    DICOFUN={}
    for elt in AST.children:
        if elt.type=='fonctionDef':
            DICOFUN[elt.leaf]=elt.children
            continue
        else :
            pass
    env=environnement(nbrRegDispo)
    print(type(env))
    compteurLabel=0
    for elt in AST.children:
        if elt.type!='fonctionDef':
            (env, compteurLabel)=compilInstruction(env, fichierSortie, elt, compteurLabel)
```

The print on `compilProgram` is to check what is `env` before I give it to `compilInstruction` (because I have an issue).

```
def compilInstruction(env, fichierSortie, instruction,compteurLabel):
    print(type(env))
    envInterne=environnement(env.taille, env.reg, env.raccess, env.faccess)
    ...
```

I've try many other way to copy `env`, but the problem seems to not come from it.
Here is what I get when I try `compilProgram` on propers arguments :

```
<class 'Environnement.environnement'> (this is the print from compilProgram)
<class 'Environnement.environnement'> (this is the print from compilInstruction)
<class 'NoneType'> (this again comes from the print in compilInstruction)
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'taille'
```

Why does the print in `compilInstruction` run twice, and why does `env` disappear between the two runs?

Comment: Unrelated to you question, but you're bound to run into that issue: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/395760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `compilInstruction` more than once:

```
for elt in AST.children:
    if elt.type!='fonctionDef':
        (env, compteurLabel)=compilInstruction(env, fichierSortie, elt, compteurLabel)
```

You have more than one elt in AST.children that is not 'fonctionDef' (a typo??), so you are invoking `compilInstruction` more than once.  That's why you get more than one print from it.  The return value of compilInstruction is being assigned to `env` and `compteurLabel`, so `env` is overwritten with None.

Comment: Okay i get it now, i'll check my compilInstruction function.Thank's a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't see a mistake further in the code. Must be too tired. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 3):

You have two print statements, which explains the printing twice.

You are overwriting `env` with the return from your first call to the `compilInstruction` function. It follows that that function is returning a `None` value as the first element of the tuple it returns.

Comment: Well, I have 3 print coming from only 2 ones in the code (I've edited my question to point on it)

Comment: @user1483213 Incidentally, why did you accept a newer answer with the same information as this one?